# Passing parameter in batch apex to another batch apex

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch with something like that (batch1) :

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    //some code here

    //in the code here I have a variable like that :
    List<Id> listOppId= new List<Id>();

    //then I put some values in this list, and I use it in a query.This is this list that I want to pass in parameter for the other batch.
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    //here I want to call the other batch (batch2) and passing it a parameter like that:
    Database.executeBatch(new batch2(listOppId));
}
```

What is the right syntaxe for doing something like that ?
Have I something special to put in the second batch (batch2) too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing would be to use `Database.Stateful` in first batch class; with that it will collect and remember all the Id's inside execute.

In second batch, you can have a property and with that you can pass the appropriate information as a parameter. Batch 2 would look like:

```
global class Batch2 implements Database.Batchable < sObject > {

    // use a property
    global final List<Id> lstOpportunityId;

    global Batch2(List<Id> lstOpportunityId) {
        // expose property to batch methods
        this.lstOpportunityId = lstOpportunityId;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < sObject > scope) {
        // processing
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```